# Problem Understanding Mark Scheme Solution

Tags: probability

I'm having a problem understanding the solution in a mark scheme. I cannot understand how the solution goes from one step to the other.

The question is:

[image]

The solution is:

[image]

I'm not sure how $2\sqrt{y - \frac{1}{12}}$ is derived from the step before.

Comment: Welcome. Posting image for critical section of your problem is discouraged. [Images](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13677/963109) may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. It is advisable to refer [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/963109) so that you can edit the body, at least for critical portions. Happy Learning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cdf of a uniform distributed varriable $X\sim U(0,1)$ is   $$F(x)= \begin{cases}
  0 & \text{for }x < 0 \\[8pt]
  x& \text{for }0 \le x \le 1 \\[8pt]
  1 & \text{for }x > 1
  \end{cases}$$

Therefore  $P\left(\frac12-\sqrt{y-\frac1{12}}<X< \frac12+\sqrt{y-\frac1{12}}\right)$ is equal to

$$F\left(\frac12+\sqrt{y-\frac1{12}}\right)-F\left(\frac12-\sqrt{y-\frac1{12}}\right)=\frac12+\sqrt{y-\frac1{12}}-\left( \frac12-\sqrt{y-\frac1{12}}\right)$$

$$=\frac12+\sqrt{y-\frac1{12}}- \frac12+\sqrt{y-\frac1{12}}=2\cdot \sqrt{y-\frac1{12}}$$